# Select an image and then select a sub-Image out of the selected image

Tags: java, swing, awt, jfilechooser

In my Java code, I am trying to browse an Image from my directory and then am trying to access to that selected image and capture an area (sub Image) from my image. I have some problems that once I select the image, I do not have access to the image (ImageIcon or BufferedImage). Because, I need its information to get a subimage out of it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class selectWindow extends JFrame{

// In this GUI project we need just one JPanel inside the JFrame
private JPanel imagePanel;
private JPanel buttonPanel;
private JButton selectImage;
private JLabel imageLabel;
File targetFile;
private ImageIcon image;
static BufferedImage targetImg;
private static final String basePath = "C:\\Users\\mroozbahani3\\Desktop";
private static final int baseSizeX = 900-110;
private static final int baseSizeY = 660;
Rectangle captureRect;
File file;

// Now let's make the constructor 
public selectWindow(){

    // The below code will close the window(JFrame), once we have click on window exit
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //lets define the default size of our window page(main JFrame), where the first value is the x and second one is y;
    setSize(900,660);
    selectImage = new JButton("Select Image");
    selectImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            image = selectButtonActionPerformed(e);

        }
    });

    imagePanel = new JPanel();
    imageLabel = new JLabel(image);
    imagePanel.add(imageLabel);

    // The below part is for JPanel related to the buttons
    buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints();
    grid.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
    // Select Buttom
    grid.gridx = 0;
    grid.gridy = 1;
    buttonPanel.add(selectImage,grid);

    // We can determine that how much of the space is going to be belonged to adjustPanel
    buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110,660));

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(imagePanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
    setResizable( false );

}


private ImageIcon selectButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(basePath);
    fc.setFileFilter(new ImageFileFilter());
    int res = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    // We have an image!
    try {
        if (res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            targetImg = rescale(ImageIO.read(file));
            return new ImageIcon(targetImg);


        } // Oops!
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You must select one image to be the reference.", "Aborting...",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (Exception iOException) {
    }
    return new ImageIcon(targetImg);

}
public BufferedImage rescale(BufferedImage originalImage)
{
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(baseSizeX, baseSizeY, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, baseSizeX, baseSizeY, null);
    g.dispose();
    return resizedImage;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException{
    JFrame gui = new selectWindow();
    gui.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: I think you need to restructure your code. Your problem will be solved if you move the sub-image processing part out of the constructor

Comment: *"Because, I need its information to get a subimage out of it."*  What 'information'?

Comment: What I mean by information: How to access to the selected image to apply a rectangular area capture? Right now, I have not applied any rectangular area capture, because I do not have access to my buffered image which is selected by my above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Image based on your selection rectangle.

See [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) for a simple way to do this.